# Automatically Submit Button click()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

Hi I have to submit a form immediatly when the page is loaded because when the form is submitted, I get the name of the JSNode tree to search and make it in evidence.

This is my script:

```
$(window).load(function() {
            $("#s").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#albero").jstree(true).search($("#q").val());
            });
        });


echo "<form id=\"s\"><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"q\" value=\"$username\"/><button type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\">Invia</button>
             </form>";
```

But the problem is that when the page is totally loaded it doesn't happen anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `trigger()` [trigger Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) same as :

```
$("#s").submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#albero").jstree(true).search($("#q").val());
}).trigger('submit');
```